# Using xcodebuild uses macOS headers

Tags: ios, xcode

Using xcodebuild in Xcode 11.2.1 to build a c library for iOS produces an error because for some reason Xcode is using the macOS headers even though the SDK is iOS. The same target builds correctly in Xcode. Does this seem like a bug? Or am I missing something?

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" -project "Project.xcodeproj" -scheme "Scheme" -destination "generic/platform=iOS" BUILD_DIR="$root/build" CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR="$root/build/temp" OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" clean build

...

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -target armv7-apple-ios8.0 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug-iphoneos\" -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fembed-bitcode-marker -index-store-path /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-arktscwurveswebmwvnpcwdblhgf/Index/DataStore -I/Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/Debug-iphoneos/include -Isrc -Ilib/jsmn -Isrc/Foundation -Isrc/BLE -Isrc/DeviceConfiguration -Isrc/DeviceDefaults -Isrc/DeviceTypes -Isrc/Header-App -I/Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -I/Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/DerivedSources -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas -F/Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/Debug-iphoneos -fembed-bitcode -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/jsmn.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/jsmn.dia -c /Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/source.c -o /Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/build/temp/Library-iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/jsmn.o
    In file included from /Users/nick/Documents/Repos/Project/source.c:1:
    In file included from source.h:4:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stddef.h:64:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug-iphoneos\" seems wrong... Maybe you should try specifying your  sdk on the xcodebuild command line e.g `xcodebuild .... -sdk macosx10.14`

Comment: I'm trying to build for iOS...it's picking up the macOS headers instead. I've also tried specifying `-sdk iphoneos` to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I had set the CPATH environment variable to try to fix a different issue:

```
export CPATH=`xcrun --show-sdk-path`/usr/include
```

Removing that fixed it.